# How can I log the time taken to start a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, puma

How can I log the start duration taken by a rails application until it is ready to serve requests ?

A naive approach by adding `puts "Rails app booted in #{(boot_start - Time.now)} seconds"` in boot.rb` does not work as intended.

```
# config/boot.rb
boot_start = Time.now

require "bundler/setup"
require "bootsnap/setup" if ENV["RAILS_ENV"] == "development"

puts "Rails app booted in #{(boot_start - Time.now)} seconds"
```

What I need is

- to print the log entry using Rails.logger defined in the environment
- be accurate as possible (expecially, include the time taken to require all gems, and ideally everything mentioned in https://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html)

Note that the naive approach I refered to above prints the duration BEFORE the web server actually starts :

```
app_1       | Database 'XXX_staging' already exists
app_1       | Rails app booted in -1.2772e-05 seconds # Not only it appears before the server is ready
app_1       | Rails app booted in -1.01e-05 seconds   # But is also duplicated for some reason
app_1       | => Booting Puma
app_1       | => Rails 6.1.3.2 application starting in staging
app_1       | => Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
app_1       | [12] Puma starting in cluster mode...
app_1       | [12] * Puma version: 5.3.1 (ruby 3.0.1-p64) ("Sweetnighter")
app_1       | [12] *  Min threads: 5
app_1       | [12] *  Max threads: 5
app_1       | [12] *  Environment: staging
app_1       | [12] *   Master PID: 12
app_1       | [12] *      Workers: 2
app_1       | [12] *     Restarts: (✔) hot (✖) phased
app_1       | [12] * Preloading application
app_1       | [12] * Listening on http://0.0.0.0:3000
```

I understand the web server is starting asynchronously and the way to measure will be coupled to the actual web server used to run the application (puma in this case) but an example of how this could be achieved using any webserver could be useful.

Comment: A very lazy solution I would use: Stream the log output, and stop the timer as soon as it prints `Listening on http://0.0.0.0:3000`.

Comment: By doing it this way, you're measuring the **real** time to boot, end-to-end. You can  guarantee "starting the clock" genuinely before starting the server (in a separate process!!), and you can guarantee "stopping the clock" after the final logged indication of rails being "ready".

Comment: While not an answer per se you might want to take a look at [`bumbler`](https://github.com/nevir/Bumbler)

Answer (score 2):

You can add the following code to your `profile/boot.rb` and then run `time bundle exec rake environment | sort`:

```rb
# config/boot.rb

require 'benchmark'

def require(file_name)
  result = nil

  time = Benchmark.realtime do
    result = super
  end

  if time > 0.1
    puts "#{time} #{file_name}"
  end

  result
end
```

It should give you an output similar to this one:

```
0.16465099999913946 ruby_parser
0.1686829999962356 sprockets/railtie
0.1764029999903869 rails
0.2461370000091847 pg_ext
0.24949699998251162 pg
0.26813800001400523 active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter
0.32413899997482076 mimemagic
0.3775960000057239 active_record/connection_adapters/postgis_adapter
0.4651059999887366 rails/all
0.549659000011161 rubocop
7.2341489999962505 /Users/leo/code/Flatlooker/config/environment.rb
bundle exec rake environment  7,05s user 2,82s system 67% cpu 14,615 total
sort  0,00s user 0,00s system 0% cpu 14,615 total
```

Another great option is the gem [Bumbler](https://github.com/nevir/Bumbler)

> Credit to https://mildlyinternet.com/code/profiling-rails-boot-time.html

Comment: Can you prove you are also measuring the time needed to start the HTTP server until the app is "ready to serve requests" as I mentioned in my original question ?